# How might I answer this past exam question relating to the value of a European option under the BMS market model?

Tags: options, black-scholes, brownian-motion

The following question, which is not homework, was taken from a past paper for a module I will soon be sitting:

> Consider a Black-Merton-Scholes stochastic market with drift $\mu = 1$, volatility $\sigma^2 = 1$ and interest rate $r = 0$. On this market there is a European option with a certain expiry $T > 0$ and a payoff
>   $$
> \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{T}{2} + \ln S_T \right)^2}
> $$
>   where S stands for the stock price. Assuming $S_0 = 1$, show that the price of this option may not exceed $\sqrt{1 + T}$.

I am struggling to answer this question. My attempt so far is as follows:

Firstly, since we are considering the stock price under the BMS market model, I **believe** that $S_t$ will be given by
$$
S_t = S_0 \exp \left( \left( r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right)t + \sigma W_t \right) = \exp \left( - \frac{t}{2} + W_t \right)
$$
Thus, denoting by $V_t$ the value of this option at time $t$, we have
$$
V_t = \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{t}{2} + \ln S_t \right)^2} = \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{t}{2} + \left( - \frac{t}{2} + W_t \right) \right)^2} = \sqrt{1 + W_t^2}
$$
and the price of this option at $t=0$ would thus be given by
$$
V_0 = e^{-rT} \mathbb{E} [V_T] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \sqrt{1 + W_T^2} \right]
$$

Assuming that I am correct thus far, I am now required to show that
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ \sqrt{1 + W_T^2} \right] \leq \sqrt{1+T}
$$
How might I do this?

Comment: BSM not BMS. And it is not called a market model.

Comment: In my lecture notes it is Black-Merton-Scholes (BMS).

Comment: Your lecturer is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the last two lines: $W_t$ should be $W_T$. Your approach is correct so far.

Use Jensen for the last step: $E[\sqrt{1+W_T^2})]^2\le E[1+W_T^2]=1+T$